# How does the Virtual Memory Management System determine the backing store location in the disk?

Tags: operating-system

In virtual memory management, swap in/out is used for managing page faults and the swap file is in a pre-allocated disk location.

But when it comes to demand paging, say for an example, when loading a program code, how does the virtual memory management system knows the actual location of the next instruction ? Does it map the executable file as a memory mapped file ?

Answer (score 0):

There are actually two separate questions here:

1) How does the [OS program loader](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loader_%28computing%29) read an executable from disk and create an address space for the program to run in?

... and ...

2) How does [OS virtual memory management](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/operating_system/os_virtual_memory.htm) work for running programs?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Need to get one thing clarified.  Say that the loader loads a program as a memory mapped file. So when a page fault occurs how does the OS know of the mapped file ? I  mean does it keep those mapped files information in the process control block or somewhere ?

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon the operating system. The description I am giving here is a simplification based upon a number of system.

Executable file describes a number of program sections. The loader reads the executable and uses it to define the sections in memory. For static data and code, the executable becomes the file used for paging (read only). For read only memory, the system page file is used for paging (read/write).

In this model, yes, the executable is a memory mapped file (although only part of it are mapped to memory). Some systems do not support direct paging to the executable.

When the program executes an instruction on a page for the first time, the memory management unit detects that the page is not in memory and that the page is backed to the executable. It then loads the page from the executable file and restarts the instruction. This is why you get a lot of page faults when a program starts up.